# Banishing Spell Cards from the graveyard

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I'm looking for cards that allow me to *banish* one or more *Spell Cards* from my own graveyard repeatedly. By repeatedly, I mean that they can be used several times per turn, including with some workaround. An example of what cards fit my needs is [Spell Striker](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_Striker), who banishes one *Spell Card* to Special Summon itself, then if I somehow get it back into my hand, I can use it again.

What I'm **not** looking for:

- *Trap Cards*. I need cards that work immediately.
- Cards that banish any number of *Spell Cards* once. I need to use them again and again, banishing my *Spell Cards* one by one. Banishing all at once doesn't help unless I can do it as often as I like.
- Cards that banish a specific *Spell Card*. Like *Spellbook* shenanigans. I need to banish generic *Spell Cards*.
- Cards that banish only non-*Normal Spell Cards*. I need to banish *Normal Spell Cards*. If a card can banish other *Spell Cards* too, it's still fine, if it can banish only *Normal Spell Cards*, no problem. But it has to be able to banish *Normal Spell Card*.

Also, Monsters that must be *Normal Summoned* are of limited use unless their effect can be used as often as I like. [Chaosrider Gustaph](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Chaosrider_Gustaph) comes to mind, but he's more or less useless because he banishes 2 cards and that's it.

From my preemptive search, I found litterally no cards that fit my description except 
[Spell Striker](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_Striker) and [Banisher of the Light](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Banisher_of_the_Light%20) / [Radiance](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Banisher_of_the_Radiance%20) (which needs to be on the field before the *Spell Card* is played). I'm hoping someone knows more cards I can use to achieve this.

Comment: Did you have a ritual Deck? I'm searching cards that matches with your criteria _and I think that I find it_, but I need that you tell me if you still looking an answer.

Comment: I'm still looking. It wasn't a ritual Deck, but if there's a method with Rituals that works towards my end goal of banishing Normal Spell Cards, I'll take it.

Comment: Ok, I make my answer with references. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

*Due that I'm not familiar with the type of Deck you have* I'll add various card suggestions:

Unfortunately, I couldn't find other card than [Frost Blast Of The Monarchs](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_Blast_of_the_Monarchs) that could be useful for your Deck and matches with your requirements.

Another options could be:

Option 1: **[Pseudo Space](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Pseudo_Space)**

> Once per turn, **you can remove from play 1 Field Spell Card in your Graveyard** to have this card be treated as that card, and gain the same effects until the End Phase.

Strategy:

- Use "[Terraforming](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Terraforming)".

---

Option 2: **[Shuffle Reborn](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shuffle_Reborn)**

> If you control no monsters: Target 1 monster in your Graveyard; Special Summon it, but its effects are negated, also banish it during the End Phase. **You can banish this card from your Graveyard**, then target 1 card you control; shuffle it into the Deck, then draw 1 card, also during the End Phase of this turn, banish 1 card from your hand. You can only use this effect of "Shuffle Reborn" once per turn.

Strategy:

- Don't set monsters on the field in the turn you use this card.
- Have *(al least)* 1 monster card in the Graveyard.
- Have *(al least)* 1 card in your hand for banish.

---

Notes:

- All previous cards can be **used once per turn**, but if you use these cards together, you can get the results that you desired.
- You can still use **Chaosrider Gustaph** o **Spell Striker** and other cards that allows you get back your summoned monsters to your hand *like Spirit monster cards*.

If you're interested, you can check this [link from Yu-Gi-Oh! Wikia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Banishes_from_Graveyard#All_OCG.2FTCG_.22Banishes_from_Graveyard.22_cards) that lists all cards that banishes from your graveyard.

You can play with the [query](http://yugioh.wikia.com/index.php?title=Special%3AAsk&q=%5B%5BClass%201%3A%3AOfficial%5D%5D%5B%5BCard%20category%3A%3AMonster%20Card%5D%5D%20%5B%5BRFP%3A%3ABanishes%20from%20Graveyard%7C%7CBanishes%20from%20your%20Graveyard%7C%7CBanishes%20from%20Graveyard%20for%20cost%7C%7CBanishes%20itself%20from%20your%20Graveyard%7C%7CBanishes%20itself%20from%20Graveyard%20for%20cost%5D%5D&po=%3FCard%20type%0D%0A%3FAttribute%0D%0A%3FType%0D%0A%3FLevel%0D%0A%3FRank%0D%0A%3FATK%20string%3DATK%0D%0A%3FDEF%20string%3DDEF%0D%0A&eq=yes&p%5Bformat%5D=broadtable&sort_num=&order_num=ASC&p%5Blimit%5D=500&p%5Boffset%5D=50&p%5Blink%5D=all&p%5Bsort%5D=&p%5Border%5D%5Bascending%5D=1&p%5Bheaders%5D=show&p%5Bmainlabel%5D=&p%5Bintro%5D=&p%5Boutro%5D=&p%5Bsearchlabel%5D=%E2%80%A6%20further%20results&p%5Bdefault%5D=&p%5Bclass%5D=%20sortable%20wikitable%20smwtable%20card-list&eq=yes) for get more concise results.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, neither of them helps (I'm really trying to banish generic Spell Cards, say Sparks), but I'm at the point where I doubt there's anything but Spell Striker :P

Comment: @scenia, you're right Did you check the link from Yu-Gi-Oh! Wikia? maybe some combination of those cards could help, and when there's not card that matches with what you're looking for, it's better create a strategy instead.

Answer (score -3):

Treasure Panda may be the card you're looking for, but you need to have tons of low level normal monsters in your deck.